# Why is the norm of $x_n(t) = t^n$ for the differentation operator equal to 1?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-operators, unbounded-operators

I am reading Kreyszig's Introduction to Functional Analysis.

He explains in an example why the differentiation operator is not a bounded operator. I cannot follow his explanation. I sometimes have difficulties wrapping my head around taking norms in function spaces.

He describes.

> Let $x_n(t) = t^n$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\Vert x_n \Vert = 1$ and $Tx_n(t) = x_n' (t) = nt^{n-1}$, so that $\Vert Tx_n \Vert = n$ and $\frac{\Vert Tx_n\Vert}{x_n}=n$.

The norm should be $\Vert T \Vert = \underset{\substack{x \in D(T) \\ x \neq 0}}{\sup} \frac{\Vert Tx\Vert}{\Vert x\Vert}$

Why is $\Vert x_n \Vert = 1$? Is there any good advice on how to think about taking the norm in function spaces to not get confused?

Happy new year!

Comment: Does he use the *supremum norm* on, say, $[0,1]$ (i.e. $||f||_\infty=\sup_{0\le x\le 1} |f(x)|$)? If not, which norm does he use?

Comment: It's impossible to tell why the value of a norm is what it is without knowing which norm is being used. Can you clarify?

Comment: I have added what I understand the norm being used. Thank you for pointing out that missing part.

Comment: What is lacking in your post is the definition of the norm in the space of functions. What even is the space of functions? continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any polynomial can understood as a vector in a vector space. In this case the author implicitly chooses the monomial basis. So with the basis $(x^n)_n$ the vector $x^n$ is a vector which $n+1$th component is 1 and every other component is zero. **This vector trivially has norm 1.** Since something like $(0, 0, .... , 0, 1, 0, 0, ...)$ represents your monomial over the monomial basis and is in fact a unit vector.

The derivative of that polynomial is $nx^{n-1}$ which is $n$ in the $n$th component and zero everywhere else. So if you were trying to pick a bound for this derivative operator working on the basis of monomial i could always find a polynomial of sufficiently large degree to violate your bound.

If you were to choose a different basis such as $(\frac{x^n}{n!})_n$ this  would no longer hold. However the linear operator which changes basis from  $(\frac{x^n}{n!})_n$ to $(x^n)_n$ would be unbounded instead.

Comment: I still have difficulties to grasp, why it is 1. I appreciate the detail you show. Could you possibly elaborate a little on the process to getting 1 as a result?

Comment: What is the norm of (0, 0, .... , 0, 1, 0, 0, ...)? This vector represents your monomial over monomial basis. In fact it is a unit vector.

Comment: That was the missing spot, thank you so much. Could you add this part to your initial answer, and I will accept it :)